# What does "XOFF ignored, mumble mumble" error mean?

Tags: nano

While trying to save a file out of Nano the other day, I got an error message saying "XOFF ignored, mumble mumble". I have no idea what that's supposed to mean. Any insights?

Comment: `CTRL-S` works (as save file) in Ubuntu 18.04, but not in 16.04.

Comment: Nice catch! Looks like it was added in v2.9.0!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You typed the XOFF character Ctrl-S. In a traditional terminal environment, XOFF would cause the terminal to pause it's output until you typed the XON character.

Nano ignores this because Nano is a full-screen editor, and pausing it's output is pretty much a nonsensical concept.

As to why the wording is what it is, you'd have to ask the original devs.

Comment: pausing its output is not nonsensical if you are using 'software flow control' from a host PC on a physical terminal and are using xoff to prevent a buffer overflow when redrawing the screen (paging down, etc). But usually that'd be handled host-side and not user-side, I suppose.

Comment: Ironically, I mostly use CTRL-X to save and quit in one go, and that always makes me confuse the X and the XOFF bits.

Comment: I believe the "mumble mumble" is a soft prank to Windows users, where `CTRL+S` is the save hotkey. Welcome to Unix

Comment: Ctrl-S is save in Nano too, but only in recent versions.

Answer (score 70):

You pressed Ctrl+S instead of Ctrl+O to save the file.  Ctrl+S is an old [flow-control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control) key combination to pause the transmission, and stop scrolling, of data to a terminal (internally, the code sent is called XOFF).  Ctrl+Q (XON) is the complement to start transmission and resume scrolling.

Nano ignores these code since it doesn't use scrolling.  The muttering is likely a result of its frustration that you didn't remember to use Ctrl+O to save.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ancient issue that is solved in modern Linux machines. Still, since Windows' WSL installs Debian 9 by default (it's past mid-2022!!), and the latest `nano` version doesn't come with Debian 9, it is very much possible to get this nonsense error from nano in a WSL shell on windows.
The right solution on WSL is to upgrade Debian 9 to Debian 11 (this is the latest version as of the time I'm writing this) which is entirely straightforward. **Please note, these instructions are meant to be run on a newly installed Debian WSL. If you have software installed on your Debian, it will get complicated!**

1. Use `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` to edit the `apt`'s sources.
2. Make sure its content is exactly as this:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
```

3. Now `clean`, `update`, `full-upgrade` and `autoremove` using the `apt`.
   During the `full-upgrade`, `apt` will ask for your permission to restart services. Select `YES`.

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade -y
sudo apt autoremove -y
```

You may now confirm you're running the Bullseye by running `cat /etc/os-release`.
Now, the `Ctrl+S` works in `nano` and you may use modern nano configuration commands in your `~/.nanorc`.

** This was all taken from https://linuxhint.com/start-debian-gui-windows-10-wsl/
** I use `wsl --install -d Debian` to install Debian.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not seem to address the current issue ("I have no idea what that's supposed to mean. Any insights?").

Comment: If you use nano on a Debian in WSL, you will get the same error as the OP. This is because nano is old and can't be upgraded.
I have explained the procedure to upgrade Debian and nano, which will make the Ctrl+S work as it should.
This post is the first entry in Google's search about "XOFF ignored, mumble mumble," whose reason is already explained here. I have written this post to help solve this problem in 2022.