# Go to file/directory in Midnight Commander by typing

Tags: mc

One thing I really miss in Midnight Commander (compared to some GUI file explorers, like f.e. Thunar) is the ability to go to a certain directory by just typing prefix of its name.

For example for a current directory containing:

```
files
other
many
many_other
some
```

Typing `man` would take me to (focus) directory `many`. Is there any plugin that would let me configure MC that way?

Comment: Relevant: [Ticket #2697 feature request: Filter as you type mode](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/2697)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You don't need any plugins. You have two options:

1. In current directory panel, type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, then type your search pattern, the cursor will jump to the matches sequentially. To toggle through all results that match the current pattern, repeat the keystroke.

   > **Note**: The [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> combination will freeze many terminal implementations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137842/what-is-the-point-of-ctrl-s) (press [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> to unfreeze), so use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> instead if that happens to you.
2. Disable `Command prompt` in `Options/Layout`.

Comment: I knew about option (1) but (2) doesn't require works without any keyboard shortcut and therefore is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: And of course you have Ctrl+o if you need the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

For os x terminal:

Press <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ option</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, you will see 'Option is Meta'.

Now works:

- <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>
- <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>
- <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>