# Configure shortcut on Vim to save file

Tags: vim, vi, vimrc

I was wondering is it possible to create a custom shortcut in `vim` or `vi` to save open file?

For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> instead of typing each time `:w`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Vim comes with a file providing some mappings intended to match Windows files. This is usually in `$VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim` (run `:echo $VIMRUNTIME` to see what it is for you). You can just do:

```
:source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
```

And get a bunch of shortcuts, including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>. See [`:h mswin.vim`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/gui_w32.txt.html#mswin.vim) for more.

Note that your terminal emulator might use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> for other purposes, but that's outside Vim.

To just create a mapping to test, do:

```
nnoremap <c-s> :w<cr>
```

Comment: Hi @muru thanks for reply. My mappings are in `/usr/share/vim/vim74`. And when I list files from there I don't have `mswin.vim`. I am on Deb8, vim version is `2:7.4.488-7`

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw it on a first sight. Everything is working. Thanks man :)

Comment: @fugitive no problem. If you're interested in using Vim better, do check out sister site [vi.se]

Answer (score 4):

*To expound on @[muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524)'s [caveat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/345976/153690) about <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> being trapped by the terminal:*

By default, a number of terminal-clients (including Cygwin) bind <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to the [freeze output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137842/153690) signal, which affects a number of commands such as `scp`, and incidentally prevents the keypress from being assigned to other things, since the console grabs it before it reaches `vim` or other applications.

***So***, for those who want to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> for purposes other than freezing output, try adding the following to your ".bashrc" file:

```
# free up ctrl+s and ctrl+q:
stty stop ''
stty start ''
stty -ixon
stty -ixoff
```