# How can I copy (yank) text in `copy-mode-vi in` Tmux, while the terminal is outputting text?

Tags: shell, terminal, tmux

I often want to copy (yank) text in `copy-mode-vi`, while the terminal is outputting text.

However, it seems impossible to reliably mark the text, while the terminal is not still (i.e., it outputs text to the terminal, making the terminal content change).

Is there any way to "freeze" the terminal, so that I can mark and copy (yank) terminal output, while the terminal is outputting text?

Comment: `CTRL+s` should temporarily suspend output. `CTRL+q` to resume

Comment: @Panki - will you elaborate? Are those Tmux, Bash (Readline), or Terminal commands?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137842/what-is-the-point-of-ctrl-s

Comment: What terminal are you using? Also, besides XON/XOFF, consider scroll-lock.

Comment: @Quasímodo - what is the effect of scroll-lock? I'm using gnome-terminal and Terminal.app

Comment: @Panki - I've read it thank you. If I press `Ctrl-s` to suspend, and the running application outputs LOTS of text, will the Terminal "blow" up, if I wait too long before pressing `Ctrl-q`? I mean, will some buffer get full?

Comment: @Panki - I assume that the "remote" side in the link you refer to, is the computer's OS?

Comment: Scroll-lock prevents the terminal window from scrolling, even if more input is generated. You can still manually scroll, differently from XON/XOFF. And yes, in any case if there is a lot of output, the buffer can't hold it all and you won't be able to copy the output.

Comment: Is it the terminal buffer that gets full? I’m just curious. Can I control the size of this buffer? What happens in the case that buffer gets full? Is it circular, so that things are overwritten?