Zsh: Non-reverse history search
In Zsh, to reverse search command history, the keyboard shortcut is Control-R. For example:
echo foo
echo bar
echo baz

Then press Control-R > Type ec > You will see echo baz > Press Control-R again > You will see echo bar.
But what if, after pressing Control-R multiple times, you have decided to move forward instead of backward? I see that people say that there is Control-S for this, but it is also said that Control-S doesn't work in many terminals by default, and it seems it doesn't work in macOS default Terminal, neither in iTerm2.

The problem with Ctrl-S however is that sometimes collides with XON/XOFF flow control. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/791800

Maybe my question is simply a duplicate, but I can't believe there is no keyboard shortcut or another way to use it out-of-the-box, without tweaking. Any ideas?

This question is similar to: Why can't I get bash to use forward incremental search?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

That handling of ^S/^Q characters that gets in the way of readline's (as used by bash) forward-search-history widget (bound to Ctrl+s in emacs mode) or zsh's equivalent history-incremental-search-forward widget (bound to both Ctrl+s and Ctrl+x s in emacs mode) when its flowcontrol option is enabled, is not done by terminals.
It is done by the tty device driver or line discipline, so computer side, not terminal side, independently of whatever terminal or terminal emulator you're using.
When it is enabled (and it is generally enabled by default) like with stty ixon, and with the default values of stty start and stty stop which on most systems are ^Q and ^S respectively, when the terminal device driver receives a ^S control character from the terminal (which generally happens when you type Ctrl+s), then it stops sending anything back to the terminal including whatever applications write to the terminal device file and the local echo of what you type until a ^Q character is received.
Note that while the application reading from the terminal won't receive that ^S character which has been handled by the terminal device driver, it will still receive further input, it's just the output that is suspended.
To disable that in zsh's line editor, you just need to turn the flowcontrol option off, like with:
set +o flowcontrol

Then zsh will do the equivalent of stty -ixon start '' stop '' whilst its line editor is active (at its prompts) and you can use Ctrl+s to invoke the history-incremental-search-forward widget or Ctrl+q to invoke the push-line widget.
Outside of zle, when running other applications, those terminal device driver flow control settings will remain unaffected. If you also want to disable them there (but beware some application may undo those settings), you can run that stty -ixon start '' stop '' manually, then the feature will be turned off everywhere, not just at zle's prompt (at least until something turns it back on)
With flowcontrol on, as noted above, you can also invoke that history-incremental-search-forward widget with Ctrl+x s and push-line is also bound to Alt+q in emacs mode (to the ^[ q sequence of characters which most terminals send upon Alt+q these days).

Can you also post an answer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/699023/why-cant-i-get-bash-to-use-forward-incremental-search?
